# What is making these subatomic honeycomb shapes and gaps in this graphene image?

Tags: experimental-physics, graphene, instrument

I just read yet another graphene discovery and saw [this STM image](http://phys.org/news/2014-05-physicists-unlimited-graphene.html):

[image]

Nice photo, it begs two questions:

1. What is that secondary honeycomb structure, the one about 20x smaller than the atoms themselves?
2. What are those gaps in it? They're fewer than one per atom, and I assume any impurities would make the primary lattice be irregular.

Comment: This could be as simple as the segmentation structure of the focal plane detector or it could represent some high-frequency artifact in the post processing. It almost certainly does not represent any physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed two honeycomb structures in the picture, but as suggested by the inset in the left bottom corner, the *smaller* one corresponds to the atoms.

The graphene in the scanning tunneling microscopy (STM) picture you show is adsorbed on an Iridium surface with Miller indices (111). Since the lattice of the Iridium atoms at the surface and the lattice of carbon atoms in graphene do not fit perfectly on top of each other, the graphene undergoes a slight (of the order of 50 pm) periodic buckling, giving rise to the honeycomb-superlattice that is observed here (typically denoted as [Moiré pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern)).

For a recent study of graphene on Iridium 111 using atomic force microscopy (AFM), see e.g. [here](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.88.201406).

Note: Don't get confused when comparing the STM image to the AFM ones - it seems that the contrast is inverted (meaning the dark dots in the STM image are actually the "hills" of the Moiré pattern).

Comment: Another way to confirm that the smaller structure are the carbon atoms is by looking at their scale, because the entire image is 15 nm by 15 nm.